# Select next item in ListView

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, selectedindex

I have a method that removes currently selected item in a ListView

```
listView1.Items.Remove(listView1.SelectedItems[0]);
```

How do I select the next in the ListView after removing the selected one?

I tried something like

```
var index = listView1.SelectedItems[0].Index;
listView1.Items.Remove(listView1.SelectedItems[0]);
listView1.SelectedItems[0].Index = index;
```

But I get the error

```
Property or indexer 'System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem.Index' cannot be 
assigned to -- it is read only
```

Thank you.

Comment: change `listView1.SelectedItems[0].Index = index;` to `listView1.SelectedIndex = index;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`ListView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2edxtd5%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) doesn't have a `SelectedIndex` property. It has a [`SelectedIndices`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.selectedindices%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) property.

> Gets the indexes of the selected items in the control.

```
ListView.SelectedIndexCollection indexes = this.ListView1.SelectedIndices;

foreach ( int i in indexes )
{
 //
}
```

Comment: I tried adding listView1.SelectedIndices = i; in the foreach statement, but I'm getting an error. (I'm still a beginner, sorry)

Comment: @Abraham What is the error? You can read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.aspx

Comment: Same as original "cannot be assigned to -- it is read only" and also "Cannot implicitly convert int to System.Windows.Forms.ListView.SelectedIndexCollection"

Comment: `ListView.SelectedIndices` returns `SelectedIndexCollection` not `int` like `i`. You should use `foreach` loop to read all indexes which are selected. And then, you can use `i` as an index of these. Please read _MSDN_ page a few times..

Comment: Okay, I will read it and come back after it working, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I had to add one more line of code to a previous answer above, plus a check to verify the count was not exceeded:

```
int selectedIndex = listview.SelectedIndices[0];
selectedIndex++;
// Prevents exception on the last element:      
if (selectedIndex < listview.Items.Count)
{
  listview.Items[selectedIndex].Selected = true;
  listview.Items[selectedIndex].Focused = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try use listView1.SelectedIndices property

Comment: Am I missing something? All I see under "listView1.SelectedX" is SelectedIndexChanged, SelectedIndices, and SelectedItems.

Answer (score 0):

If you delete an item, the index of the "next" item is the same index as the one you just deleted. So, I would make sure you have `listview1.IsSynchroniseDwithCurrentItemTrue = true` and then

```
var index = listView1.SelectedItems[0].Index;
listView1.Items.Remove(listView1.SelectedItems[0]);
CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(listview).MoveCurrentTo(index);
```

Comment: "CollectionViewSource doesn't exist in current context" am I missing a using statement?

Answer (score 0):

I've done this in the following manner:

```
int selectedIndex = listview.SelectedIndices[0];
selectedIndex++;
listview.Items[selectedIndex].Selected = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually had to do this:

```
        int[] indicies = new int[listViewCat.SelectedIndices.Count];
        listViewCat.SelectedIndices.CopyTo(indicies, 0);
        foreach(ListViewItem item in listViewCat.SelectedItems){
            listViewCat.Items.Remove(item);
            G.Categories.Remove(item.Text);
        }
        int k = 0;
        foreach(int i in indicies)
            listViewCat.Items[i+(k--)].Selected = true;
        listViewCat.Select();
```

to get it to work, none of the other solutions was working for me.

Hopefully, a more experienced programmer can give a better solution.